# Mouse Left Click Sometimes Doesn't Register | Sometimes Deselects When Held In

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I've had this problem in the past, and reinstalled the OS and it fixed the problem. I don't want to reinstall this time because I have so much stuff on my PC, so maybe one of you can be of help. My mouse is acting weird, and I know this isn't a hardware problem. Sometimes when I try to left click, it doesn't register. Sometimes when I have something selected, for example if im dragging a window, it will deselect it and stop, then i have to start dragging it again. I have windows 7. Like I said, I know this isn't a hardware issue because when I had this problem in the past, I just reinstalled my OS and it fixed it. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I see that you said you "know" it's not hardware problem. But: 1. When is the last time you cleaned out the button contact areas inside your mouse? 2. Have you tried a different USB port?  3. Have you tried the mouse on a different computer, if available? 4. How does the system behave if you unplug the mouse, reboot and then plug it back in? 5. Have you tried a different mouse on the problem computer without making any other changes? Is this a wired mouse or a wireless mouse; if wireless, have you changed the batteries?

Comment: I have tried a different USB port. It's a wired USB mouse. I honestly think this is a software problem, so as of now I'm running malwarebytes and avast, hopefully I get some luck. Still, I'm open to suggestions and any fixes if anyone has any in mind. thanks for your response, i appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you get a different mouse and  swap it.  If the problem goes away its hardware(the mouse).  You can borrow one or buy a cheep one.

Comment: Sounds like a mouse problem to me. Seen these same symptoms many times.